# complexity order of the interior point method

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, convex-optimization, computational-complexity, linear-algebra

I was wondering why the complexity order of the interior point method is O()^3 or O()^3.5?

Much appreciate your time and consideration.

Answer (score 5):

For a linear program in standard form
\begin{align}
\min_{x} \ \ \ & c^{T}x\\
\text{s.t.} \ \ \ & Ax = b,\\
& x \geq 0,
\end{align}
where the constraint matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ (i.e., $m$ constraints and $n$ variables) has full row rank (which implies $n \geq m$), the best-known interior-point algorithms require $O(\sqrt{n} \log(1/\epsilon))$ iterations to achieve a precision of $\epsilon$. See for instance the [textbook of S. Wright on interior-point methods](https://doi.org/10.1137/1.9781611971453) for a detailed description.

This means that after $O(\sqrt{n} \log(1/\epsilon))$ iterations, you get a primal-dual solution which is feasible and optimal up to some tolerance measured by $\epsilon$.
Now, each iteration requires the solution of a linear system of size $m$, whose complexity is roughly $O(n^{3})$ (recall that $n \geq m$).

This gives an overall complexity of $O(n^{3.5} \log(1 / \epsilon))$ to solve the problem *to $\epsilon$ accuracy*.

PS:

- I am voluntarily vague w.r.t $\epsilon$ since the OP was about complexity w.r.t $n$. There are plenty of details in Wright's book.
- The $O(n^{3})$ is a slight upper estimate: AFAIK, the theoretical complexity for matrix inversion is around $O(n^{2.37})$. In practice, all this is not as relevant since we deal with sparse matrices.

Comment: This adds to the PS above:  https://erlingdandersen.blogspot.com/2013/11/complexity-of-solving-conic-quadratic.html